# Guice does not load Bindings

Tags: java, groovy, guice

Interface -

```
public interface Add {
    public int add(int a, int b)
}
```

Implementation 1 -

```
class MartianAdd implements Add 
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return -a+b;
}
}
```

Implementation 2-

```
public class SimpleAdd implements Add {
public SimpleAdd() {}
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b
}
}


class Bindings extends AbstractModule {
protected void configure() {
    bind(Add).annotatedWith(Names.named('Earth')).to(SimpleAdd)
    bind(Add).annotatedWith(Names.named('Mars')).to(MartianAdd)
}
}
```

Main class -

```
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Bindings())
    @Named('Mars') Add a = injector.getInstance(Add)
    print a.class
    print a.add(5, 8)
}
}
```

Exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for in.ksharma.Add was bound.
  while locating in.ksharma.Add
```

Why doesn't Guice load my bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem, I believe:

```
@Named('Mars') Add a = injector.getInstance(Add)
```

You're just *asking* for an instance of `Add` - the fact that the variable you're assigning the result to has the `@Named` annotation is irrelevant to Guice. I believe you'll need to use `Injector.getInstance(Key)` with a key for the right class *with the right name binding*, e.g.

```
Add add = injector.getInstance(Key.get(Add, Names.named('Mars')))
```